# How can I start a new activity from a switch case I run inside a Service in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, service, switch-statement

Hello I try to build an Android app. I have an Activity which calls an Intent Service. Inside the Service I have implemented a switch case. My idea is in one case call an activity to do some Google Maps things and in other case call another activity.

Is it possible and how can I do it ?

Comment: By your question what I can understand is that you want to call two different activities from switch case according different situations right?

Comment: Yes, from a switch case inside a Service, not an activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can open activity using startActivity method in a service class just like in an activity clas.

Example:

```
Intent intent;

switch(action){

    case 1:{
        intent = new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class);
        break;
    }

    case 2:{
        intent = new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class);
        break;
    }

}

if (intent != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

or in short

```
switch(action){

    case 1:{
        startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class));
        break;
    }

    case 2:{
        startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class));
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Finally made it work. So for other people: you should add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).